# Serial interface loading configuration

Tags: cisco, router

Just asking something I cannot find in the cisco doc
A teacher told today that when a serial interface goes up the router tries to load configuration from it!
Is it true or can you give me some reference?

Thanks!

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not specific to serial interfaces. Check out the "service config" statement: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/fundamentals/command/reference/cf_book/cf_r1.html#wp1076778

Comment: `service config` applies at boot, not when an interface comes up.

Answer (score 1):

If the link encapsulation is PPP, then this is *very broadly* true -- PPP can negotiate a great many parameters. But this is a long way from getting any configuration "cli" content.